# How do i execute a logic after Hangfire job has succeded, i mean the Succeded state?

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, hangfire

I tried these action job filter methods, but what I actually need is, I want to call a method after the Job id has been executed successfully or it has internally failed after it gave the Job id.

```
public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
        { 
            //Log event
        }

        public void OnCreating(CreatingContext filterContext)
        {
            //Log event
        }

        public void OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext)
        {
            //Log event
        }

        public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext context)
        {
            //Log event
        }

        public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext context)
        {
            //Log event
        }

        public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
        {
            //Log event
        }

        public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
        {
            //Log event
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use either OnPerformed OR OnStateApplied filters? I think those should be the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Hangfire can build an execution chains. If you want to schedule next job after first one succeed, you need to use `ContinueWith(string parentId, Expression<Action> methodCall, JobContinuationOptions options);` with the `JobContinuationOptions.OnlyOnSucceededState`.

More detailed information you can find here: https://indexoutofrange.com/Don%27t-do-it-now!-Part-5.-Hangfire-job-continuation,-ContinueWith/

Comment: I wish you could share some code examples.